# Bind date to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have date format like this `/Date(1495623815523)/`.How can I bind this in a input field in normal `dd-MM-yy` format.

```js
var app=angular
  .module('plunker', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.dateString = '/Date(1495623815523)/';
     $scope.formattedDate = $filter('jsonDate')($scope.dateString);
  })
app.filter('jsonDate', function () {    
    return function (date) {
        return new Date(date.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="exampleInput">Date input</label>
    
    <input 
      type="date"  
      ng-model="dateString" 
    /><br>
   //its working for label<br>

   <label>{{dateString | jsonDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</label>
  </form>
  
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your ng-model value to **Date Object** with proper format, because you are using input type "date".

```js
var app=angular
  .module('plunker', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.dateString = '/Date(1495623815523)/';
     $scope.formattedDate = $filter('jsonDate')($scope.dateString);
     $scope.dateStringFormatted =$filter('date')($scope.formattedDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
     console.log( $scope.dateStringFormatted);
  })
app.filter('jsonDate', function () {    
    return function (date) {   
        return new Date(date.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="exampleInput">Date input</label>
    
    <input 
      type="date"  
      ng-model="dateStringFormatted" 
    /><br>
   //its working for label<br>

   <label>{{dateStringFormatted | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</label>
  </form>
  
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
var app=angular
  .module('plunker', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.dateString = new Date(1495623815523);
     $scope.formattedDate = $filter("date")($scope.dateString, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
  })
app.filter('jsonDate', function () {    
    return function (date) {
        return new Date(date.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="exampleInput">Date input</label>
    
    <input 
      type="date"  
      ng-model="dateString" 
    /><br>
   //its working for label<br>

   <label>{{dateString | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</label>
  </form>
  
</section>
```

Comment: By default I have to show the `dateString` in date field.